# Comparing coefficients with polynomials

Tags: polynomials

$x^5-x^4-2x^3+2x^2-3$ is identical to $(x+1)(x-2)Q(x)+ax-b$, where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial

Comment: The polynomial $Q(x)$ can be of degree 3 when you compare coefficients.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: So i shall let Q(x) be Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D. Ah I right?

Answer (score 1):

By degree reasons $Q(x)$ is a monic polynomial of degree $3$. Comparison of coefficients gives
$$
Q(x)=x^3 +2,
$$
which in turn determine $a$ and $b$, namely $a=2$ and $b=-1$.

Comment: Sorry but can u show my how u got to this?

Comment: As you said, write $Q(x)=x^3+Ax^2+Bx+C$ and compare coefficients. Both polynomials of degree $5$ are equal if and only if the coefficients of them are equal.

Comment: I’ll have to expand (x+1)(x-2) right? Then multiply in the Q(x). I ended up with a=2, b=1

Comment: Yeah @Cate definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Since the formula $$x^5-x^4-2x^3+2x^2-3=(x+1)(x-2)Q(x)+ax-b$$ is valid for all $x$ it is valid also for

$$x=2:\;\;\;\; 32-16-16+8-3 =0+2a-b \implies \boxed{2a-b=5}  $$ and

$$x=-1:\;\;\;\; -1-1+2+2-3 =0-a-b\implies \boxed{a+b=1}$$

Now solve this system and you are done.